# Laravel ajax internal servor 500 (internal server-error)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a shopping cart which is stored in session and I want to refresh the session without reloading the page
I have tried this: 
View:

```
<a href="#" id="product" data-id="{{ $product->id }}" class="item_add single-item hvr-outline-out button2">Add to cart</a>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#product').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        let url = "{{ route('add-to-cart') }}";
        let id = $(this).data('id');

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {product_id: id, _token: "{{ Session::token() }}"}
        })
        .done(function() {
            console.log("success");
        })
        .fail(function() {
            console.log("error");
        })
    });
});
```

Route:

```
Route::post('/add-to-cart', 'ProductsController@addToCart')->name('add-to-cart');
```

ProductsController:

```
public function addToCart(Request $request)
{
    if ($request::ajax()) {
        $id = $request->product_id;

        $product = Product::find($id);

        if (Session::has('products')) {
            $products = Session::get('products');
            $products[] = $product;
            Session::put('products', $products);
        }

        else {
            $products = array($product);
            Session::put('products', $products);
        }

        return response()->json();
    }
}
```

And when I click add to cart it gives 500 (Internal Server Error) in the console

Comment: Check your log file, there's a hint somewhere in there.

Comment: @aynber where to find that file ?

Comment: storage/logs/laravel.log

Comment: It's in your storage folder. `app/storage/logs` for 4.2, `/storage/logs` for 5.

Comment: @aynber these are the last two logs:
`#38 /home/dlydyv9i/public_html/testing/case-shop/index.php(54): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#39 {main}`

Comment: You should add the full log concerning the 500 error to your question.

Comment: @aynber the last log is from 3 hours ago

Comment: @Wistar do you men that? 
`jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4 POST http://weband.bg/testing/case-shop/add-to-cart 500 (Internal Server Error)send @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4ajax @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4(anonymous function) @ VM4726:332dispatch @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3r.handle @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3
VM4726:341 error`

Comment: @AngelMiladinov I meant in your laravel.log, the log should contains several lines concerning the 500 error that you report here. If you aren't sure which one it is, rerun you ajax query and take the log that correspond to that time.

Comment: @Wistar the last log in the file is from 3 hours ago

Comment: @AngelMiladinov You have tried to run the ajax again and you do not get any more recent log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're accessing the `ajax()` method statically (using `::`), when you should be using `->` instead:

```
if ($request->ajax()) {
```

**Using the Laravel log file**

As mentioned in the comments, Laravel is probably telling you this in `storage/logs/laravel.log`, complete with a long call-stack trace (the lines that you mentioned, beginning with "#38" and "#39"). Just scroll up to before "#1" and you'll find your culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel doesn't allow without passing X-CSRF-TOKEN,
following is my working example hope it helps you.

Route :

```
Route::post('block-user','UserController@BlockUser');
```

Now you need to add ajax setup before your ajax call so in
blade.php :

Add this in header

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

My script like :

```
<script>
//Ajax setup
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

//Ajax call

    $(".blockuser").bootstrapSwitch();
    $('.blockuser').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function () {
        var userid = $('#userid').val();
        $.ajax({
            url:'/block-user',
            data:{user_id : userid},
            type:'post',
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Controller :

```
public function BlockUser(Request $request)
{
    $userid = $request->get('user_id');
//perform operation
}
```