# Laravel : Insert data into database using Bootstrap Modal

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, bootstrap-modal

I want to insert some data into database using Bootstrap Modal. But the problem is Save button doesn't work properly on Bootstrap Modal as I couldn't insert the data into database through form. If anyone could help me to find it please!?

Here is the form part in blade:

```
<div id="myAlert" class="modal hide">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button">×</button>
        <h3>Create User</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12">
                <div class="widget-box">
                    <div class="widget-content nopadding">
                        <form action="#" method="get" id="userForm" class="form-horizontal">
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Name :</label>

                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input class="span11" placeholder="Name" type="text">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Email :</label>

                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input class="span11" placeholder="Email" type="email">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Password</label>

                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input class="span11" placeholder="Enter Password" type="password">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Confirm Password</label>

                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input class="span11" placeholder="Confirm Password" type="password">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer"><a data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Confirm</a> <a
                data-dismiss="modal" class="btn" href="#">Cancel</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the Ajax Part :

```
 $('#userForm').on('success.form.fv', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            action:"{{ url('/register') }}",
            data: $form.serialize()
        });
    });
```

Comment: What about the controller?

Comment: basic authentication I have used ..Register controller.the problem is save button doesn't work.means nothing happened while I click on that button

Answer (score 0):

You need the submit button. Try to put this code inside your form.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
```

Problem with your current Confirm button is: 1) he don't have `type=submit`; 2) he is outside the form.

Answer (score 0):

first of all add `type="submit"` to your button

secondly check your network tab in the dev tools in your browser and check the request does it go to `/register` or not ?
if the request is hitting `/register` what's the parameters ?

Answer (score 0):

Change form method `get` to `post`

I answer here for ajax call

[Laravel ajax internal servor 500 (internal server-error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40850606/laravel-ajax-internal-servor-500-internal-server-error/40858807#40858807)

Answer (score 0):

Your input type elements are missing name attribute

```
<input class="span11" placeholder="Name" name="name" type="text">

<input class="span11" placeholder="Email" name="email" type="email">

<input class="span11" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" type="password">

<input class="span11" placeholder="Confirm Password" name ="confirm_password" type="password">
```

You then retrieve the content using Request or Input by passing the value of the name attribute

Answer (score 0):

At first change your form method from get to **post**. Then add save button with id btnSave.
Ajax :

```
$("#btnSave").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault()
    var $form = $("#userForm");
    $.ajax({
        type: $form.attr('method'),
        url: $form.attr('action'),
        data: $form.serialize(),
        success: function (data, status) {
             if(data.error){
                return;
            }
            alert(data.success); // THis is success message
            $('#myModal').modal('hide');  // Your modal Id
        },
        error: function (result) {

        }
    });

 });
```

In controller :

```
public function store(Request $request)   
{   try {
    $inputs = $request->all();  
    ModelName::create($inputs);
    $data = ['success' =>'Data saved successfully'];        
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $data = ['error' =>$e->getMessage()];         
    }        
    return Response::json($data);     
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Form part in blade:

```
<div class="modal-footer"><a data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnAdd">Confirm</a></div>
```

Ajax Part

```
        $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '{{url('/register')}}',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $('#userForm').serialize(),
                success: function (object) {

                },
                error: function (result) {

                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: I have used your solution.there is no error in console now but not submitted data.

Comment: @Hola its working fine for me, can you show to backed code.